# Powershell: Copying a file to remote server using New-PSDrive

Tags: python, powershell, copy, remote-server, network-drive

I need to copy a file from my Windows server to another remote server using Webdav.

The first thing I do is map a network drive in PowerShell:

```
[String]$WebDAVShare = '\\xxx.xxxxx.xxx@SSL\DavWWWRoot\webdav'
New-PSDrive -Name "W" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $WebDAVShare -Credential $cred
```

This works, I can see all remote files and dirs when I do a list. Now, when I want to copy a file I get an error:

```
Copy-Item ImportSheets\ToDo\xxxxx.xls -Destination W:\import\xxxxx.xls
```

> ```
> Copy-Item : A device attached to the system is not functioning.
> At D:\Automation-Scripts\drive.ps1:35 char:6
> +      Copy-Item ImportSheets\ToDo\xxxxx.xls -Destination W ...
> +      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
> ```

Also when I try to copy the file in Python I get an error:

```
shutil.copy('ImportSheets\ToDo\xxxxx.xls', 'W:\import\xxxxx.xls')
```

or

```
copyfile('ImportSheets\\ToDo\\UHA_HP_DM_Autobot.xls', 'W:\\import\\UHA_HP_DM_Autobot.xls')
```

results in

> ```
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'W:\\import\\xxxxx.xls'
> ```

I don't mind if the solution is in PowerShell or Python.

Comment: Please read what is in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.2#parameters) for parameter `-Persist`

Comment: And, while you're at it, for the parameter `-Global`. (Overall, I'd say ditch PowerShell for this task. Use a batch file, `net use`, and a regular `copy` command. That's two lines of bog-standard commands that don't require any mental gymnastics.)

Comment: Adding to Theo's comment... You'll also have to include the global scope. Seems like there's a bug but only specifying `-Persist`.

Comment: Thnx for your answers. I changed the drive mapping to:
`New-PSDrive -Name "W" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $WebDAVShare -Scope Global -Persist -Credential $cred`
but now I got this error:
`New-PSDrive : The network resource type is not correct`